# 2-Way synchronization SharePoint 2013 and Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, windows

I have a question regarding Sharepoint 2013 calendar and Outlook 2010 calendar.
Is there a possibility to "connect" my Sharepoint calendar to my Outlook calendar? I do not mean the built-in option to synchronize the sharepoint calendar with outlook - since that would be having 2 different calendars. I want to simply synchronize the appointments made on the sharepoint calendar to outlook. When I make a change in the sharepoint calendar to a specific appointment, it should be immediately synchronized to Outlook. The same goes the other way around.

Is there any way to work this out?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's a popular request, but this is not possible out-of-the-box. You might find some third party tools, but it's a technically difficult scenario with many sources of synchronization conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
That is sad. If that does not work, how about synchronizing one single event in a calendar? For example: "Event X" on monday. If I change the time it starts in my personal Outlook Calendar, it should also be automatically changed in the SharePoint Calendar. The same goes for the name. 
So is there a possibility to synchronize specific meetings/appointments from a personal Outlook Calendar to the  Sharepoint Calendar? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same, not out of the box. In the Office 365 world you could use Flow to synchronize calendars. Then again, I don't know if this specific scenario with SharePoint is supported.